# Can't get access token google drive sdk

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I want to use Google drive api in my application, that's why I'm using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications. But I have a problem - I can't get an access token. At first I successfully get the authorization code using the following request:

```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&
  redirect_uri=[my redirect_uri from from Developers Console]&
  response_type=code&
  client_id=[My client ID for native application from Developers Console]
```

Then I try to get an access token using received authorization code using the following request:

```
   POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: accounts.google.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   code={My uthorization code}&
   client_id=[My client Id]&
   client_secret=[My clien secret]&
   redirect_uri=[my redirect_uri from from Developers Console]&
   grant_type=authorization_code
```

All the time server returns 400. Can you tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Trace the http request
2. Go to OAuth2 Playground and do the same
3. Spot the difference

It may be that you aren't urlencoding the params